Java.Lang.Exception: 'Bind service failed' when trying to create an object instance from aar
This is a MAUI app running in an Android device, the aar library is provided by a third party unitech vendor, an RFID reader device.
The exception Java.Lang.Exception: 'Bind service failed' is thrown on the generated code within the Android Java Library Binding
I pass the generated constructor the Platform.CurrentActivity.ApplicationContext as the only argument. i.e.
reader = new Com.Unitech.Lib.Htx.HT730Reader(Platform.CurrentActivity.ApplicationContext);

this goes into this generated method:
        // Metadata.xml XPath constructor reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.unitech.lib.htx']/class[@name='HT730Reader']/constructor[@name='HT730Reader' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.content.Context']]"
        [Register (".ctor", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V", "")]
        public unsafe HT730Reader (global::Android.Content.Context? context) : base (IntPtr.Zero, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer)
        {
            const string __id = "(Landroid/content/Context;)V";

            if (((global::Java.Lang.Object) this).Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            try {
                JniArgumentValue* __args = stackalloc JniArgumentValue [1];
                __args [0] = new JniArgumentValue ((context == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : ((global::Java.Lang.Object) context).Handle);
                var __r = _members.InstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (__id, ((object) this).GetType (), __args);
                SetHandle (__r.Handle, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                _members.InstanceMethods.FinishCreateInstance (__id, this, __args);
            } finally {
                global::System.GC.KeepAlive (context);
            }
        }

and the exception is thrown in the FinishCreateInstance line
This is how the binding project looks like
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-android</TargetFramework>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>21</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="unitechRFID_v1.0.30.aar" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

The same thing works ok in their Xamarin app but I am trying to migrate the example to MAUI
I am not familiar with Android development so I might be missing something basic here.
